# Wouldn't Stack Overflow look better this way?

Tags: feature-request, design

[image]

Notice the position of "Top Questions" and the "Ask Question" button. The same could be said about the other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: No, it is consistent with the look of filtered pages. If they went with your proposed change they would have to mess with sizes to get it all to fit. I suspect most users rarely land on the Home page of SO.

Comment: I think you need to understand that the new thing is "white space". More margins and more (higher) line spacing and more top bars with more white space in that too ;)

Comment: Yes, removing useless space so that we can reach the content more effectively does look better.

Comment: \*takes a loooong look at the current style to spot the difference\* Erm, okay… honestly, I didn't even take note of that whitespace before.

Comment: Sure, that very first page, with default everything, it looks fine. What about when you visit the same page (template-wise) with any other parameters, like, say, [a tag page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bzxU.png)? Everything shifts and you have to retarget mouse clicks, etc., etc.. I'm thinking maybe the designers thought of things besides "how can I make this one page pretty"....

Comment: @HereticMonkey i do tend to agree with that assessment, however, it appears as though the questions page and the home page don't actually share that area. visually there's subtle differences that clue in on it being a different set of code, and then when you actually look at the DOM, it's quite different indeed. I'd assume the home page is using something older, it being a page they're likely spending less time on. (specifically, the line of content starting directly below the line with "Ask Question" in it.)

Comment: The current layout allows them to add more sort options later if they want to without space being an issue.

Answer (score 12):

[image: mockup with the ask question removed altogether]

I suggest it should look like the above (yes, it the "ask question" button is deliberately removed). Asking a question should not be the easiest action to spot on the page. Don't we want people to *search* before asking? How about not showing the button *at all* until the user makes a search?

Asking a new question (at least nowadays) is supposed to be [the last resort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/11407695) (not as "the final frontier" but as the last step in a complex process of learning), not the first thing that comes to one's mind - so let's make the UI work towards that goal too.

Comment: I'd like the "filter" button to be part of the home page list as well. aka merge the two designs back together and improvem both

Comment: Gonna have a lot of searches for "how do I ask a question". This would probably also increase both the number of people going to the Help Center (which would be good!) and the number of people posting questions in the answer section.

Comment: @BSMP I'd vote, but I am completely out of TinyVotes for today - have a thumbs up :)

Comment: @KevinB same - the subtle differences between the too pages are quite annoying, and I personally keep forgetting which one contains which options - a unification of options would definitely a good thing (at least from my POV)

Comment: Then, new users are likely to search "how to ask", which should return only one result: `/help/how-to-ask`. Win-win!
 

Comment: Yes, Jeff Atwood once said something about the deliberate placement of the Ask Question button (on the Stack Overflow podcast?). I think it was part of the original design.

Comment: @PeterMortensen methinks so - it sure is not accidental (and that it also prominently shows up on individual Q&As too), after all, UX is exactly what influences user behavior - make one action easier to do than the other / more prominent, and results will follow.

Comment: Perfection, no more radiantly blue button to coax people into prematurely outsourcing and making their life more miserable than it needs to be.